# string comparision using regex and test

Tags: javascript, regex, conditional-statements

how to return isValid = false when test(E) for both regex

```
let arr =[A_MANAGER,B_MANAGER,C_MANAGER,A_EMPLOYEE,C_EMPLOYEE]

arr.map((item)=>{
let isValid = ( new RegExp("MANAGER").test(item) && !new RegExp("EMPLOYEE").test(item)) 
console.log(isValid)
})
```

**problem statement**

```
let M= MANAGER, E=EMPLOYEE

M M = true
M E = true
E M = true
E E =false
```

Comment: None of the given examples show a case where "MANAGER" and "EMPLOYEE" are in the same item. Is the current question an accurate, minimal example of your question?

Comment: Please make yourself more clear map will actually use only a single item at a time and you are passing only a single string to both condition which will always return on the basis of one i.e item and not like M M = true. Please clarify more and also please make your array as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to parse the input array into two separate arrays of employees and managers.  Then, starting with a collection of all people, detect whether or not a person be a manager and employee at the same time.

```js
var arr = ["A_MANAGER", "B_MANAGER", "C_MANAGER", "A_EMPLOYEE", "C_EMPLOYEE"];
var employees = [];
var managers = [];
var all = ["A", "B", "C"];

for (var i=0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if (/_MANAGER$/.test(arr[i])) {
        managers.push(arr[i].replace(/_.*$/, ""));
    }
    else {
        employees.push(arr[i].replace(/_.*$/, ""));
    }
}

for (var i=0; i < all.length; ++i) {
    if (managers.includes(all[i]) && employees.includes(all[i])) {
        console.log("Person " + all[i] + " is both a manager and an employee.");
    }
    else {
        var type = managers.includes(all[i]) ? "manager" : "employee";
        console.log("Person " + all[i] + " is a " + type + " only.");
    }
}
```

Note that ideally you should also maintain a separate list/array of all people.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this with regex but also passing the actual array to compare values. Currently you are just matching the current item in both times and not the current and succeeding one.

You can do something like

```
let arr =['A_MANAGER','B_MANAGER','C_MANAGER','A_EMPLOYEE','C_EMPLOYEE']
arr.map((total,key,arr)=>{
 if(arr[key+1] != undefined){
  return !(new RegExp(/EMPLOYEE/).test(total) && new RegExp(/EMPLOYEE/).test(arr[key+1]));
}
//Output : True,True,True,False
```

You can check the working example here
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GS103YAMF97P